# Inline local variables in C language

Tags: variables, inline, local

I would like to split 1 normal function to several inline functions due to especially test strategy and operation speed.

```
void a(void)
{
    b();
    c();
}
```

Meanwhile, if the both inline function have huge local variables with same name, how are those handled by the compiler?

```
inline b(void)
 {
     unsigned long tmp1;
     unsigned long tmp2;
            .....
 }
inline c(void)
 {
     unsigned long tmp1;   ==> same name with inline function b
     unsigned long tmp2;   ==> same name with inline function b
            .....
            continued...
 }
```

When b and c are being inlined, are the local variables made hidden independently?

Sorry for my poor english.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, the compiler takes care of that stuff. Wouldn't compiling your sample code provide the answer to this more quickly than posting here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the compiler will compile your functions correctly, with or without using `inline`. The `inline` specifier is not just simple source text replacement, but is rather a compiler feature that gives the compiler a hint about how you would like your code compiled.

Answer (score 0):

`inline` is a compiler feature to improve some performance for those intensively used functions. It will not change any rule of the local variable statement and will not cause conflict in your case.